# Can you define probes in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to figure out if you can configure Kubernetes probes in Helm charts. I've seen some Git issues about this, but they concerned specific projects. Is there a standard way in which Helm allows for the configuration of probes?

Comment: There's nothing special about them, they'd show up in a normal place in a Pod spec, maybe in your `templates/deployment.yaml` file.  Is there a more specific problem you're running into?

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't know what the "normal" place for them is, since helm charts are a bit different then Kubernetes specs. I wasn't able to find any documentation about it, so I was confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes probes can be defined in Helm charts by using the 'livenessProbe' and 'readinessProbe' fields in the pod's container spec like so:

```
containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: my-app-image
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: http
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 10
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /readiness
        port: http
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

Comment: Can you also do this with startup probes?